# Storybook webpack repeatedly rebuilding (hot reloading over and over?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, storybook

I am using Storybook for a NextJS project and when I run it, it keeps rebuilding over and over and never stops. My CPU goes crazy and it drains my battery. After the build finishes, it immediately starts rebuilding. It's like it is hot reloading over and over.

```
webpack building...
webpack built preview 4f726ddcef7523fb95db in 20394ms
webpack building...
webpack built preview 4f726ddcef7523fb95db in 8835ms
webpack building...
webpack built preview 4f726ddcef7523fb95db in 8763ms
webpack building...
webpack built preview 4f726ddcef7523fb95db in 7692ms
webpack building...
webpack built preview 4f726ddcef7523fb95db in 10166ms
webpack building...
webpack built preview 4f726ddcef7523fb95db in 8239ms
webpack building...
webpack built preview 4f726ddcef7523fb95db in 8956ms
webpack building...
webpack built preview 4f726ddcef7523fb95db in 7353ms
webpack building...
```

My `main.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../**/*.stories.mdx', '../**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  presets: [path.resolve(__dirname, './next-preset.js')],
};
```

My `next-preset.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (baseConfig, options) => {
    // Modify or replace config. Mutating the original reference object can cause unexpected bugs.
    const { module = {} } = baseConfig;

    const newConfig = {
      ...baseConfig,
      module: {
        ...module,
        rules: [...(module.rules || [])],
      },
    };

    // Absolute imports
    newConfig.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve(__dirname, '../'));

    // TypeScript with Next.js
    newConfig.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
      include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../')],
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['next/babel'],
            plugins: ['react-docgen'],
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    newConfig.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');

    // Less
    // Remove original less loader
    newConfig.module.rules = baseConfig.module.rules.filter(
      (f) => f.test.toString() !== '/\\.less$/'
    );
    newConfig.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.less$/,
      include: [
        // Include antd to rebuild
        /[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*antd/,
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
      ],
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'less-loader',
          options: {
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    //
    // CSS Modules
    // Many thanks to https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6055#issuecomment-521046352
    //

    // First we prevent webpack from using Storybook CSS rules to process CSS modules
    newConfig.module.rules.find(
      (rule) => rule.test.toString() === '/\\.css$/'
    ).exclude = /\.module\.css$/;

    // Then we tell webpack what to do with CSS modules
    newConfig.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.module\.css$/,
      include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../')],
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    newConfig.resolve.alias['/images'] = path.resolve(
      __dirname,
      '../public/images'
    );

    return newConfig;
  },
};
```

My `preview.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { RouterContext } from 'next/dist/next-server/lib/router-context';
import * as NextImage from 'next/image';

require('../src/assets/styles/antd.less');

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
};

export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <RouterContext.Provider
      value={{
        push: () => Promise.resolve(),
        replace: () => Promise.resolve(),
        prefetch: () => Promise.resolve(),
      }}
    >
      <Story />
    </RouterContext.Provider>
  ),
];

Object.defineProperty(NextImage, 'default', {
  configurable: true,
  value: (props) => {
    const height = props.height;
    const width = props.width;
    const quotient = height / width;
    const paddingTop = isNaN(quotient) ? '100%' : `${quotient * 100}%`;
    let wrapperStyle;
    let sizerStyle;
    let sizerSvg;
    let toBase64;
    let imgStyle = {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      boxSizing: 'border-box',
      padding: 0,
      border: 'none',
      margin: 'auto',
      display: 'block',
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      minWidth: '100%',
      maxWidth: '100%',
      minHeight: '100%',
      maxHeight: '100%',
      objectFit: props.objectFit ? props.objectFit : undefined,
      objectPosition: props.objectPosition ? props.objectPosition : undefined,
    };

    if (
      width !== undefined &&
      height !== undefined &&
      props.layout !== 'fill'
    ) {
      if (props.layout === 'responsive') {
        wrapperStyle = {
          display: 'block',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          position: 'relative',
          boxSizing: 'border-box',
          margin: 0,
        };
        sizerStyle = {
          display: 'block',
          boxSizing: 'border-box',
          paddingTop,
        };
      } else if (props.layout === 'intrinsic' || props.layout === undefined) {
        wrapperStyle = {
          display: 'inline-block',
          maxWidth: '100%',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          position: 'relative',
          boxSizing: 'border-box',
          margin: 0,
        };
        sizerStyle = {
          boxSizing: 'border-box',
          display: 'block',
          maxWidth: '100%',
        };
        sizerSvg = `<svg width="${width}" height="${height}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"/>`;
        toBase64 = Buffer.from(sizerSvg).toString('base64');
      } else if (props.layout === 'fixed') {
        wrapperStyle = {
          overflow: 'hidden',
          boxSizing: 'border-box',
          display: 'inline-block',
          position: 'relative',
          width,
          height,
        };
      }
    } else if (
      width === undefined &&
      height === undefined &&
      props.layout === 'fill'
    ) {
      wrapperStyle = {
        display: 'block',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        margin: 0,
      };
    } else {
      throw new Error(
        `Image with src "${props.src}" must use "width" and "height" properties or "layout='fill'" property.`
      );
    }

    return (
      <div style={wrapperStyle}>
        {sizerStyle ? (
          <div style={sizerStyle}>
            {sizerSvg ? (
              <img
                style={{ maxWidth: '100%', display: 'block' }}
                alt={props.alt}
                aria-hidden={true}
                role='presentation'
                src={`data:image/svg+xml;base64,${toBase64}`}
              />
            ) : null}
          </div>
        ) : null}
        <img {...props} decoding='async' style={imgStyle} />
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

I have no idea what to do here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue on [GitHub (Webpack Building Constantly)](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/14342) describing a similar behavior. They solved it by changing the glob of the stories [(1)](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/14342#issuecomment-811081265) [(2)](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/14342#issuecomment-811093347) [(3)](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/14342#issuecomment-811093347).

```
Before (constantly re-building): stories: ['../**/*.mdx', '../**/*.stories.tsx']
After (no issues): stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.tsx']
```

--

```
This works: stories: ['../../src/components/SomeComponent/index.story.js']
This loops: stories: ['../../**/*.story.js']
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!